# Writing Traits in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, traits, coldfusion-9

Is there a way to writes Reuseable code(`Traits`) like PHP or Javascript in Coldfusion

As this seems to be a great idea of writing Traits and using in Different Classes where they are needed.

Comment: I don't know what a trait is but there are lots of ways to write re-useable code in ColdFusion.  You have included files, custom tags and User Defined Functions.  In fact you can even have custom tags that include JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

And I found the following PHP code to be interesting:

```
<?php
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}
?>
```

My take on things like this.

CFML is different from other programming languages in that it has lots of built-in functions. I use objects all the time. The objects I use are `application.cfc`, FW/1 Controllers, DI/1 / FW/1 Services, DI/1 / FW/1 Beans, and ORM back objects.

Each and every one of these has a built in set of expectations and usages. None of them are plain objects. It has been a long time since I wrote a plain object. I would much rather use a more feature rich object.

CFML also has member functions on its variables. This makes them similar objects.

Last but not least, If I really had to pull in functionality from multiple locations, I would just create an instance of an object inside of another.

**Disclaimer:** I currently work on an application with about fifty cfc and hundreds of functions. All of them are needed but some refactoring might be useful.

I could see one or two places where traits might helpful, but I can think of other things to do first.